# When is a function $k$-valued, where $k$ is a field?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, terminology

I am reading algebraic geometry from class notes and I am not able to find the meaning of this line despite web searching a lot.

> Question: What does it mean when a function is $k$-valued on a set $X$, where $k$ is a field?

Kindly let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A $k$-valued function $f$ on a set $X$ is a function $f\colon X\to k$.